# Python socket taking wrong port

Tags: python, networking, port, nat

Why is my python script behaving this way?
I give it the instruction to connect via port 7777 but instead it is going over 45604.

I am NOT using `socket.bind((socket.gethostname(),port))`

Instead I work either with `socket.bind(("0.0.0.0",port))`
or with `socket.bind(("127.0.0.1",port))`
so I'm working local here. Why does my computer reroute the ports?
There should be no need for that, shouldn't it? Can I somehow disable it locally?

[image]

Comment: Can you give code for `Jhonson.py` ?

Comment: I can upload to stack exchange when I'm finished, for now I have my answer, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am answering in the absence of any of your actual code.. So I have to make assumptions here:

1) You have server (right side in picture) listening on port 7777.

2) You are running a client on the same machine (left side of picture) that is connecting to the server.

So, the client (on the left shell) is connecting to the server (right shell window).  The server is listening on 7777 and the client is connecting to the server from 45604 (client and server cannot occupy the same port on the same machine!)

Put another way, the client is "sending" to port 7777 *from* port 45604. Maybe that makes better sense?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I feel a little naive for not knowing this basic stuff, but you made it crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

A TCP connection is defined by 4 numbers: source IP address, source port, destination IP address, destination port.

The connection goes from 127.0.0.1 port 45604 to 127.0.0.1 port 7777.

The source port (45604) is a value chosen by the system  from a wide range of unused ports (it is called an ephemeral port), because your program did not set a specific source port.

Comment: Well I honestly did not know i could set a specific source port. Will have to digg a little deeper. Thank you

Comment: @clockw0rk I'm glad you find my answer helpful. It is very common not to set the client's port. The value usually does not matter and the operating system knows better which one is unused.

Comment: Ok, so I would just ignore it completly I guess. Thank you for your time